# Protractor Interactive debugging session (elementExplorer) - how to import .ts or .js file?

Tags: typescript, debugging, protractor

According to [Protractor Debugging](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/debugging.md), I start Protractor interactive session by typing:

```
protractor --elementExplorer
```

I have TypeScript file with definition of additional methods that I would like to use in interactive session.

I noticed that it is not possible to just copy-paste them from source file to elementExplorer: it seems that `elementExplorer` try to execute each line.

For example, copy-paste following method will not be allowed:

```
getElement(elTitle: string) {
    return this.getElements().filter(function(elem) {
        return elem.getAttribute('title').then(function(text) {
            return text === elTitle; });
        }).first();
}
```

[[image: when copy pasting method definition[2]]
Is it possible to import TypeScript or JavaScript file into elementExplorer / interactive Protractor session?

Comment: I'm not sure if we can import a Typescript/javascript file into protractor debugger, but to copy-paste any function, first convert the multiline function into a single line using any online tools like http://tools.knowledgewalls.com/onlinemultilinetosinglelineconverter and then paste the converted single line code into the debugger console(Typescript functions won't work).

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. Unfortunately, when I try to copy-paste class or function definition, it gives me `Error while evaluating command: SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` error

Comment: remove `:string` from `getElement(elTitle: string)`. it should work fine.